# Upload File in Laravel not working in ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I've created a simple upload function, it works on windows XAMPPP but when I move it into production in ubuntu it doesnt work here is my code:

```
 if($request->file('input_img')) {

        $image = $request->file('input_img');
        $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('\tcpdf\examples\images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $User->signature_link          = $name;
        }
```

I've tried the following in ubuntu server:

Sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/link-to-my-folder

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/link-to-my-folder

Comment: Ubuntu directory separator is `/`.

Comment: change destination path as `$destinationPath = public_path('tcpdf/examples/images/');`